# Can a point source be focused to a point by a mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection

Does a shape exist such that light from a point source at f1 will be focused by a mirror of that shape to another point f2? What is the name or equation for such a surface? And what happens to the light if the point source is moved closer to or further away from the mirror?

[image]

Yes, I know technically an ellipse can do this, but I want to know if it can be done without the mirror on the other side of f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, ellipses (or ellipsoids of revolution in three dimensions) with the focal points at $f_1$ and $f_2$ can do this. They are also the unique shapes that can do this. Keep in mind though that there are infinitely many such ellipses, defined by the equation
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$
where the the focal points lie on the x-axis, the origin is midway between them, and $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$ is equal to half the distance between them. There is a different ellipse with the desired property for each positive value of $b$: the semi-minor axis of the ellipse.

The mirror does not have to completely enclose both points. Just as most spherical mirrors are not complete spheres, an elliptical mirror could consist of only part of the ellipse (or ellipsoid). This part will still direct all incident rays in such a way as to form a point image at $f_2$. The larger the mirror surface, the brighter the image. In other words, you don't need a reflecting surface to the right of $f_2$.

If you bring the object closer to the mirror, there will no longer be a point image in perfect focus. There will be a fuzzy image to the right of $f_2$. The larger the mirror surface, the fuzzier the image.

Comment: For some reason I thought that an ellipse was doing this by acting like two parabolic mirrors facing each other.